# Populating a variable based on the total of each level

Tags: r, dataframe, tidyverse, lubridate

I was looking for help with a problem I'm currently stuck on in a project (reprex after the text).

Basically what I'm trying to do is populate a variable with a criteria of levels, based on the number of times a patient recorded data for the week in order to explore quality of recording.

The criteria for levels is as follows:

```
3+ readings/week == "4",
3 readings/week == "3",
2 readings/week == "2",
1 reading/week == "1",
NA == "0"
```

I first created a new variable for weeks by using the week() function of lubridate, which gave me week numbers based on where the dates were in the year. Ideally I'd like to allocate week numbers in ascending order (1-n), starting at 1 from the first date the patient recorded to the last date.

Been thinking of using a for loop but currently using case_when. The problem I'm currently encountering is setting the condition to check the frequency of levels for each patient id in order to then assign the criteria.

Any help would be beneficial as I've been stuck on it for most of today, many thanks (reprex below).

```
library(lubridate)
#> Warning: package 'lubridate' was built under R version 3.5.3
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'lubridate'
#> The following object is masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     date
library(tidyverse)
#> Warning: package 'tidyverse' was built under R version 3.5.3
#> Warning: package 'ggplot2' was built under R version 3.5.3
#> Warning: package 'tibble' was built under R version 3.5.3
#> Warning: package 'tidyr' was built under R version 3.5.3
#> Warning: package 'readr' was built under R version 3.5.3
#> Warning: package 'purrr' was built under R version 3.5.3
#> Warning: package 'dplyr' was built under R version 3.5.3
#> Warning: package 'stringr' was built under R version 3.5.3
#> Warning: package 'forcats' was built under R version 3.5.3

##Variables##

patientid <- c("-2147483646", "-2147483646", "-2147483646", "-2147483646", "-2147483646", "-2147483646", "-2147483646", "-2147483646", 
               "-2147483646", "-2147483646", "-2147483646", "-2147483646", "-2147483646", "-2147483646", "-2147483646", "-2147483646")

date <- c("2018-08-06", "2018-08-07", "2018-08-07", "2018-08-07", "2018-08-15", "2018-08-15", "2018-08-15", "2018-08-20", "2018-08-20",
          "2018-08-20", "2018-08-27", "2018-08-27", "2018-08-27", "2018-09-03", "2018-09-03", "2018-09-03")

week <- week(date)

adherence <- ""

test.df <- data.frame(patientid, date, week, adherence) #test df with variables above

##Dataframe and attempt##

table(test.df$week) #See frequency of each
#> 
#> 32 33 34 35 36 
#>  4  3  3  3  3

test.df <- test.df %>% #Dataframe
  mutate(
    patientid = as.factor(patientid),
    date = as.Date(date),
    week = as.factor(week))

adherence <- test.df %>% #Attempt to create if/else/else if loop to populate adherence
  mutate(week = 
           if(count(week) > 3){adherence == "4"})
#> Error in UseMethod("summarise_"): no applicable method for 'summarise_' applied to an object of class "factor"
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a version of what you want:

```
test.df <- data.frame(patientid, date) #test df with variables above

test.df %>% #Dataframe
  mutate(
    patientid = as.factor(patientid),
    date = as.Date(date),
    week = floor_date(date, "week")
  ) %>% 
  group_by(patientid, week) %>% 
  summarize(total_readings = n(),
         adherence = case_when(is.na(total_readings) ~ 0L,
                               total_readings < 4 ~ total_readings,
                               total_readings >= 4 ~ 4L,
                               TRUE ~ NA_integer_))
```

The only thing this doesn't take care of is the week sequencing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `add_count` to count number of instances of each week. With `pmin` we select the value which is minimum between 4 and `n`.

```
library(dplyr)
test.df %>% add_count(week) %>% mutate(week_num = pmin(4, n))
```